# Прогрузка ajax запроса

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте, есть запрос

$.post(

```
      "/work.php",
```

{

```
  id_wait_confirm: id_wait_confirm
```

},

onAjaxSuccess

```
      );
```

function onAjaxSuccess(data)

{

```
  alert (data);
```

}

как прикрутить такой индикатор только к этому запросу, а не ко всем запросам на странице

```
$(function() {
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
    // Show loader
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // Hide loader
});

$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
    // Hide loader
});
```

});

Спасибо

Comment: сделал так : 
$(document).one('ajaxSend', function(){ $('#ind_ajax').css('display','block'); });
     $(document).one('ajaxComplete', function(){ $('#ind_ajax').css('display','none'); });
     $(document).one('ajaxError', function(){ $('#ind_ajax').css('display','none'); });

через .one работает, может кому-то пригодится

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так: наверняка же $.post() не прсото так, а в обработчике некоего события. Вот там же, в обработчике, перед отправкой запроса показать индикатор. А уже в функции onAjaxSuccess скрывать его.

Comment: Пробывал, показать после click а скрытие заношу в data. После выполнения, начинает срабатывать на все запросы.

Comment: а зачем в data?